# when case planshipdate<today sqlsever & mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

i need to show all records when

1. planshipdate<today ==> late collection
2. plandeliverdate<today ==> late delivery
3. status name in (tendered, booked) ==> no EDI update

Comment: You must clarify your data model.

Comment: "show all records" implies a filter, but your cryptic bullet points imply logic for a computed value. Please clarify your question, focus on a specific dbms engine, and provide sample input and desired output. Mind reading does not work so well at a distance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know it's CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN planshipdate<NOW() THEN 'late collection'
    WHEN plandeliverdate<NOW() THEN 'late delivery'
    WHEN statusname in ('tendered', 'booked') THEN 'no EDI update'
  END
FROM
  ...
```

You just need to decide which database you're using and swap the NOW for getUtcDate if it is sql server